# What is the difference between "How close is your house to the highway" and "How far is your house from the highway"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, descriptive-grammar

I was talking to a friend of mine when I asked:

> How close is your house to the highway?

He said that, since I was discussing distance, it would have been more grammatically correct to ask:

> How far is your house from the highway?

Is there any real difference between the two when speaking to someone (or in this case, texting)?

Comment: Your friend doesn't know what he's talking about. Both versions are fine - it's just a matter of whether the speaker [texter? :] wants to focus on *how close* he hopes the house will be, or *how far away* he fears it might be.

Comment: In actual usage, close vs. far reflects the mindset of the asker, or serves to make it a "leading question" by framing it in the direction the asker wants you to think about it.

Comment: This question is analagous to the distinction between "How full is your glass" vs. "How empty is your glass," a distinction that is so rooted in context that it's become an idiomatic litmus test of one's worldview.  *Is the glass half empty or half full?*  Point being, it's all about perspective and context.  Both are certainly grammatically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically the two sentences mean the exact same thing.

Some *implications* might be different.

For instance,

> "How close are you to the highway?"

could mean that it might be a bit too noisy for your friend ...

while

> "How far are you from the highway?"

might be suggesting he is afraid of getting lost in the maze of picturesque scenic roads once he's off the exit ramp.

Neither is more grammatically correct than the other, though.